# OPNsense/pfsense on Proxmox with LACP, VLANs and Multi-WAN

Tags: router, vlan, proxmox, lacp

I want to set up an OPNsense router (of pfsense if OPNsense sould not work as desired) on Proxmox. I have multiple WANs as well as multiple local VLANs. Since I have more VLANs than physical ports I obviously will have to use VLAN-trunking. And since routing between VLANs on a single gigabit line will be slow I want to use LACP to bond multiple ports to serve as my trunk.

My multiple WAN connections (4 at the moment) have a sum of less than 1 gigabit. I could use VLANs here as well in order to save on ports (= more ports for the LACP).

So, a simple setup (ignoring proxmox of now) would look like this

[image]

Now for the difficult part: I want to set this up as a VM on proxmox. One reason being, that, should the hardware fail, I could use a different server to run the VM on. But not all my proxmox hosts have the same number of ethernet ports. Therefore I am planning the following setup:

- one, VLAN aware bridge in Proxmox
- one LACP bond in proxmox which is a member of a VLAN aware bridge
- the OPNsense VM would only get two network cards (the two mentioned bridges) and configure everything as VLANs over these bridges.

So now, in case I have to switch to another host, I could replace the LACP bond with a simple VLAN aware bridge over only one gigabit port. (lower speed, but things would still work)

**Is there any fault in my setup? Something I missed?**

**Am I right, that OPNsense would not see any change when switching the host = no config changes needed**

**Do I need to use Open vSwitch in order for other VMs to be able to use the router?**

**What is the expected overhead of this setup compared to a bare-metal setup?**

Comment: I really wonder why you have four WAN links. I don't see a good reason for having more than two.

Comment: simple: there is no availiability for one single fast WAN. So, we have to use multiple DSL lines. Having only one fast line would obviously be much better, but at the moment the lowest price for fiber was 12x the cost of DSL + one-time installation fees. At another location we have 3 WANs: 1x fiber, 1x DSL backup, 1x LTE backup. But at that location the HW router used supports it out-of-the-box.

Comment: oh, this is interesting setup and use-case! (I'm not helpful here, sorry :) + I hope by this time you've resolved your problem)